# Grouping the pagers - Drupal

Tags: views, paging

I have a view with full pager, i am showing 10 items per page.
Now pager shows up like...

```
1    2    3    next ›    last »
```

I want to to show each pager number from which count it will start and end...like

```
1-10    11-20    21-30    next ›    last »
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have 2 accounts ? I see same posted here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107124/how-to-change-views-pager-links

Comment: Aha, that my other colleague, stuck with the same issue. :D

Comment: See answer here.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107124/how-to-change-views-pager-links